# Theorem styles with emph

Tags: theorems

LaTeX Overleaf tells me that `\newcommand{theorem}{Theorem}[\fcolorbox{blue}{orange}{subsection}]` is an error.
Why??
My goal is to have this:
**Theorem of ... chapter.section.subsection**, with chapter.section.subsection in orange-emphasized with blue frame.
How must I do?
Thank you so much

**First Edit:** I have implemented your tips --- Thank you to have answered --- but I did not obtained what I desired. I know this **thmtools**-package.
Could It be help me?
Thank you so much again.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message, as well as a small compilable example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  There's not enough information here now to do anything but guess, and that's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I am not sure what error Overleaf is displaying, but my first guess would be the missing backslash before "theorem" :


`\newcommand{\theorem}{Theorem}[\fcolorbox{blue}{orange}{subsection}] `

Comment: @Lukas Puck almost certainly meant to write `\newtheorem` rather than `\newcommand`.

Comment: you still haven't identified the document class and (all) theorem packages you are using, so it's not possible to answer your question without guessing.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the optional argument at the end of `\newtheorem` is the name of a counter that you're numbering within. No more, no less. (Also, I assume you meant to say `\newtheorem` instead of `\newcommand`.)

There are a couple ways to get your desired result. One approach is to incorporate the formatting into the definition of `\thetheorem` which is responsible for printing the theorem number. This would look like:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\thetheorem}{}
    {\fcolorbox{blue}{orange}{\thesubsection.\arabic{theorem}}
```

Of course, this will cause the theorem numbers to be boxed and colored if you use `\ref` (or `\cref`) to refer to them by label. I'm not at a computer with LaTeX installed on it right now to work out the necessary magic with `\p@theorem` to clear out the `\fcolorbox{blue}{orange}` in a reference.

Another approach would be to load the `amsthm` package and then declare a new theorem style with the formatting you want. The full documentation is available with `texdoc amsthm` and again, this is untested, but you should be able to do the following:

```
\newtheoremstyle{colorednum}
   {}{} % Use default spacing before and after
   {\itshape}{} % No indent and italic body (again the default settings)
   {\bfseries}{.} % Print "Theorem 1.3.1" in bold with a period after
   { } % default space after theorem head
   {\thname{#1}\thnumber{ \fcolorbox{blue}{orange}{#2}\thnmote{ (#3)}}
\theoremstyle{colorednum}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
```

The last line before `\theoremstyle` is specifying that the theorem number should be enclosed in the `\fcolorbox` as specified.