# Theorem Styles with \ref and \colorbox

Tags: theorems, ref, colorbox

Yesterday I publicated a question, link: [Theorem styles with emph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605406/theorem-styles-with-emph).
But I still have other problems.
My code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amscd}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[tight, italian]{minitoc}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pgn, .pdf}


\captionsetup{labelformat=empty,textfont=sl}


\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\boxed{\arabic{footnote}}}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

%\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheoremstyle{colorednum}{}{} % Use default spacing before and after
{\itshape}{} % No indent and italic body (again the default settings)
{\bfseries}{.} % Print "Theorem 1.3.1" in bold with a period after
{ } % default space after theorem head
{\thname{#1}\thnumber{ \colorbox{orange}{#2}\thnmote{ (#3)}}
\theoremstyle{colorednum}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]}

%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\thetheorem}{}{\fcolorbox{blue}{orange}{\thesubsection.\arabic{theorem}}}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\newtheorem{Pitagora}{Pitagora's Theorem}[subsection]
\label{PITAGORA}
\begin{Pitagora} ...
\begin{proof} ...
\end{proof}
\end{Pitagora}
In Theorem \ref{PITAGORA}... .
\section{Second Section}
\newtheorem{Cayley-Hamilton}{Cayley--Hamilton's Theorem}[subsection]
\label{Cayley_Hamilton}
\begin{Cayley-Hamilton} ...
\begin{proof} ...
\end{proof}
\end{Cayley-Hamilton}
\newtheorem{Cayley-Hamilton_C}{Corollary by the Theorem \ref{Cayley_Hamilton}}[subsection]
\label{CayleyHamilton}
\begin{Cayley-Hamilton_C} ...
\begin{proof} ...
\end{proof}
\end{Cayley-Hamilton_C}

\end{document}
```

These are all packages that I use. Could Someone go into conflict with what I desire?
If so, what among these?
Could you improve my tex-code, please?
Thank you so much

**First Edit:** What I'd like to have is:

1. The number of theorems in `\colorbox{orange}`;
2. When I write `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}` I'd like to have `\textbf{\textcolor{blue!50}{Dimostrazione}}` %Dimostrazione means Proof (I'm Italian);
3. A clever ref of theorem, for example in my code I wrote **Cayley-Hamilton's Theorem 2.0.1**, when I write `Corollary of Theorem \ref{...}` I'd like to have **Corollary of Theorem 2.0.1 \colorbox{orange}{2.0.2}**.

Comment: If you replace "Pitaogra" with "Pitagora", your test document will compile without further ado.

Comment: Already edit, Sorry and Thank you. I edited my question.

Comment: Off topic: The loading of packages is disorganized, and at least two packages (`mathtools` and `amsthm`) are duplicated.  It would be better if packages with related purposes are grouped, for example all packages related to fonts.