# Continuous vertical lines in begin{array}

Tags: arrays, vertical-spacing

About this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}

\[\Tonde{\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}\textrm{Id}_{i-1}&0_{\mathbb{K}^{i-1}}&O_{i-1}&\overline{b_{h \in[1,i-1]}}\vspace{1mm}\\\cline{1-3}0^T_{\mathbb{K}^{i-1}}&0&0^T_{\mathbb{K}^{n-i+1}}&\overline{b_i}\ne0\vspace{1mm}\\\cline{1-3}O_{n-i+1}&0_{\mathbb{K}^{n-i+1}}&\textrm{Id}_{n-i+1}&\overline{b_{k\in[i+1;n]}}\end{array}}\]

\end{document}
```

I'd like that vertical lines of this array are continuous. How Must I Do?
Thank you so much

Comment: please always post code as a complete document, the lines would be continuous by default but you added `\vspace{1mm}`  which is presumably there to add a 1mm gap.

Comment: Already edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}

\newcommand{\Tonde}[1]{\left(#1\right)}

\begin{document}
\[
\Tonde{
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
  \textrm{Id}_{i-1}&
  0_{\mathbb{K}^{i-1}}&
  O_{i-1}&
  \overline{b_{h \in[1,i-1]}}
  \\[1mm]                            % <--
  \cline{1-3}0^T_{\mathbb{K}^{i-1}}&
  0&
  0^T_{\mathbb{K}^{n-i+1}}&
  \overline{b_i}\ne0
  \bigcup
  \\[1mm]                            % <--
  \cline{1-3}O_{n-i+1}&
  0_{\mathbb{K}^{n-i+1}}&
  \textrm{Id}_{n-i+1}&
  \overline{b_{k\in[i+1;n]}}
\end{array}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How did you get that matrix to appear?

Comment: @Puck, you are welcome. That matrix is just a partial screenshot.

Comment: Ok and how did You realized this scrennshot?

Comment: @Puck just view the pdf result of the test document then depending on your operating system you can usually cut and paste it here, on windows `windows-key shift s` lets you snip out the relevant part then usual control-v to paste it into a post

Comment: Thank you. Would you be so kind to answer a question posted here ?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605480/theorem-styles-with-ref-and-colorbox?noredirect=1#comment1518242_605480